# two-times analytic continuation of the domain

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

Lets imagine that D - given domain (strip) on upper half plane H, and G - its image (connected) under mapping f with required properties. The image has curved side (not stright line, like, polygons!). I want to continue my domain (image) analytically twice. Can I see, likewise polygon that after two time analytical continuation, the latest domain has connection with initial withing fractual transformation? i.e. f**(z)=(a*f(z)+b)/(c*f(z)+d), where f** - two times analytical continued.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do relate the two-time analytically continued function and the initial function on given curved,connected domain?

Comment: I will detach very soon a decent answer by myself…